# height:auto Causing 1px Shrink in Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

In the sidebar of my wordpress theme looks fine in all browsers except Chrome. In chrome, the images resizes to being 1px shorter in height - making the images slightly blurry.

The CSS for the image element is

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

The resizing is preferred for mobile devices, but I don't understand the change on a full screen monitor when in Chrome.

Is there a quick fix for this, or do you need to see more of the code to determine the issue?

Comment: if you can replicate it on a standalone page - let's say by creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), we might be able to help you out I guess

Comment: Good point. Created a jsFiddle and doesn't seem to be an issue there, so must be something else going on with the div styling. Working on replicating it...

Comment: Are you sure that the images are not displayed at their full height when using `height:auto`? My instincts say that they are stretched by 1 pixel without it, caused by some other CSS elsewhere.

Comment: @Mr Lister, you're right there is some CSS elsewhere that is causing the issue, but I'm unable to identify exactly where. I'm having trouble recreating it it in jsfiddle, but will keep trying. Also, I noticed that the image is it's normal height when the browser window is reduced a little. Once it is stretched past 980px, the image resizes the height by 1px. Weird thing this is only in Chrome.

Comment: Couldn't figure out what was going on with the CSS, but I made the image 1px narrower and it fixed the height issue. Not sure how or why, but it did.